How can I simultaneously acquire Image and Point Cloud data from an iPhone and send it via WebSockets to FoxGlove?
I'm trying to acquire the camera image and the point cloud data from an iPhone. I plan to stream both simultaneously using WebSockets. These messages will be sent to FoxGlove to visualize the data.
My issue is that when I send the camera image alone, I can see it in FoxGlove. Similarly, when I send only the point cloud data, it is displayed correctly. However, I cannot see both at the same time. If I send the camera image, the point cloud data doesn't appear, and vice versa. When I try to send both simultaneously, only the camera image is visible.
Here is the code in Swift:
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import ARKit
import Combine
import simd

class Camera: NSObject, ObservableObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    private var videoOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    private let systemPreferredCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
    private let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "video.preview.session")
    
    private let session = ARSession()
    
    
    @Published var image: CGImage?
    var addToPreviewStream: ((CGImage) -> Void)?
    @Published var webSocketManager = WebSocketManager()
    
    @Published var pointCloudData: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)] = []
    
        private var lastFrameTime: CFAbsoluteTime = 0
        private var frameInterval: CFAbsoluteTime = 1.0 / 15.0 // 15 FPS target
        private var lastSendTime: TimeInterval = 0
        private let minInterval: TimeInterval = 1.0 / 15.0 // 15 Hz for point cloud data
    
    private let ciContext = CIContext()
    
    // Camera Info Properties
        var height: Int
        var width: Int
        var distortionModel: String
        var D: [Double]
        var K: [Double]
        var R: [Double]
        var P: [Double]
        var binning_X: Int
        var binning_Y: Int
        var roi: [Double]
    
        //private var pointCloudDataHandler: PointCloudData
    
    
    init(webSocketManager: WebSocketManager,
            height: Int = 144,
            width: Int = 192,
            distortionModel: String = "plumb_bob",
            D: [Double] = [],
            K: [Double] = [],
            R: [Double] = [],
            P: [Double] = [],
            binning_X: Int = 1,
            binning_Y: Int = 1,
            calibrationData: AVCameraCalibrationData? = nil) {
           
           // Initialize camera info properties
           self.height = height
           self.width = width
           self.distortionModel = distortionModel
           self.binning_X = binning_X
           self.binning_Y = binning_Y
           self.roi = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] // Default ROI
           
                    
           
           if let calibrationData = calibrationData {
               // Lens Distortion
               self.D = calibrationData.lensDistortionLookupTable?.map(Double.init) ?? []
               
               // Validate D
               assert(!D.isEmpty, "Distortion coefficients D must not be empty")
               
               // Intrinsic Matrix (3x3)
               let intrinsicMatrix = calibrationData.intrinsicMatrix
               self.K = [
                   Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][2]),
                   Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][2]),
                   Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][2])
               ]

               // Ensure K contains 9 elements:
               assert(self.K.count == 9, "Intrinsic matrix K must have exactly 9 elements")

               
               // Extrinsic Matrix (3x3)
               let extrinsicMatrix = calibrationData.extrinsicMatrix
                   self.R = (0..<3).flatMap { row in
                       (0..<3).map { col in Double(extrinsicMatrix[row][col]) }
                   }
               
               assert(R.count == 9, "Rotation matrix R must have exactly 9 elements")
               
               
               // Projection Matrix (4x4)
               self.P = [
                       Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[0][2]), 0.0,
                       Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[1][2]), 0.0,
                       Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][0]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][1]), Double(intrinsicMatrix[2][2]), 0.0
                   ]
               
               // Validate P
               assert(P.count == 12, "Projection matrix P must have exactly 12 elements")
               
               if distortionModel == "plumb_bob" {
                   assert(D.count == 5, "Distortion model 'plumb_bob' requires exactly 5 coefficients")
               }
               
               
           } else {
               // Initialize D, K, R, P with default values provided by David Portugal
               self.D = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] // Default distortion coefficients
               
               let fx = Double(width) // Approximate focal length as image width
               let fy = Double(height) // Approximate focal length as image height
               let cx = Double(width) / 2.0 // Principal point x-coordinate (image center)
               let cy = Double(height) / 2.0 // Principal point y-coordinate (image center)

               self.K = [
                       fx,  0.0, cx,
                       0.0, fy,  cy,
                       0.0, 0.0, 1.0
                   ]
               //Camera Matrix
               self.R = [ 7.1998919677734375e+02, 0.0, 3.5894522094726562e+02,
                          0.0, 7.1998919677734375e+02, 4.8530447387695312e+02,
                          0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]
               
               //Projection Matrix:
               self.P = [ -1.19209290e-07, 0.0, 1.00000012e+00,
                           0.0, 0.0, -1.00000024e+00,
                           0.0, 0.0, 1.00000012e+00,
                           0.0, -1.19209290e-07, 0.0 ]
           }
            // TO SEE /camera and /camera_info - Cant see /point_cloud
           //self.pointCloudDataHandler = PointCloudData()
           
           super.init()
           setupARSession()
           self.webSocketManager = webSocketManager
           
           Task {
               await configureSession()
               await startSession()
           }
        
        //CameraManager.shared.addVideoDelegate(self)
       }
    
    

    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    
    // MARK: - ARKit Setup
        func setupARSession() {
            config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
            config.frameSemantics = .sceneDepth
            config.planeDetection = .horizontal
            session.delegate = self
            session.pause()
            session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        }
    
    
    
    
    private func configureSession() async {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            guard let systemPreferredCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back),
                  let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: systemPreferredCamera) else {
                print("Error: Unable to access the camera.")
                return
            }
        
        

            do {
                try systemPreferredCamera.lockForConfiguration()
                
                // Select the default or ARKit-compatible format
                if let compatibleFormat = systemPreferredCamera.formats.first(where: { format in
                    format.isVideoBinned == false && format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.contains { $0.maxFrameRate >= 30 }
                }) {
                    systemPreferredCamera.activeFormat = compatibleFormat
                } else {
                    print("Warning: No compatible format found, using the current active format.")
                }
                
                systemPreferredCamera.unlockForConfiguration()
                 
                
                // MARK: - ARKit Setup
                    func setupARSession() {
                        config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
                        config.frameSemantics = .sceneDepth
                        session.delegate = self
                        session.pause()
                        session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
                    }
            } catch {
                print("Error configuring camera: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            defer {
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            }

            // Set the session preset for testing (e.g., low resolution)
            captureSession.sessionPreset = .low

            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sessionQueue)

            // Add inputs and outputs to the session
            if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) && captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
                captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            } else {
                print("Error: Unable to add input/output to capture session.")
            }
        }

    
    func startSession() async {
        guard !captureSession.isRunning else { return }
        
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
                self?.captureSession.startRunning()
                continuation.resume()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            clearMemory() // Clean up resources when stopping
        }
    }
    
    lazy var previewStream: AsyncStream<CGImage> = {
        AsyncStream { continuation in
            addToPreviewStream = { cgImage in
                continuation.yield(cgImage)
            }
        }
    }()
    
    private func cgImageFromSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> CGImage? {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            print("Error: Could not get image buffer from sampleBuffer")
            return nil
        }
        
        
        
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        return ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
    }
    func clearMemory() {
        // Clear any residual data stored in image buffers (if necessary)
        self.image = nil
        // Reset last frame time if needed
        self.lastFrameTime = 0
    }
}


extension Camera: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        let currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        
        // Skip frames if they are too close in time
        guard currentTime - lastFrameTime >= frameInterval else { return }
        lastFrameTime = currentTime
        
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            print("Error: Could not get image buffer from sampleBuffer")
            return
        }
        
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        guard let cgImage = self.ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else {
            print("Error creating CGImage")
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
            return
        }
        
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        
        // Send to preview stream
        self.addToPreviewStream?(cgImage)
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            // This method should now be faster due to the above optimizations
            self.addToPreviewStream?(cgImage)
            
            
            // Compress and send over WebSocket
            if let imageData = self.cgImageToData(cgImage) {
                let width = cgImage.width
                let height = cgImage.height
                let encoding = "rgba8"
                let step = width * 4 // Assuming 4 bytes per pixel
                
                let test = self.getCameraInfo()
                self.webSocketManager.send(message: test)
                
                let json = self.convertToJSON(imageData: imageData, height: height, width: width, encoding: encoding, step: step)
                self.webSocketManager.send(message: json) // Send this in background to avoid blocking
                
            }
            
            Task {
                if await self.memoryUsageIsHigh() {
                    self.clearMemory()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // A function to check if memory usage is high
    func memoryUsageIsHigh() async -> Bool {
        // Implement logic to determine if memory usage is above a threshold
        // For example, you can use mach_task_basic_info to get current memory usage
        var info = mach_task_basic_info()
        var count = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<mach_task_basic_info>.size) / 4
        
        let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: 1) {
                task_info(mach_task_self_, task_flavor_t(MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO), $0, &count)
            }
        }
        
        if result == KERN_SUCCESS {
            let usedMemory = info.resident_size
            let threshold: UInt64 = 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 // Set a threshold 3GB
            return usedMemory > threshold
        }
        
        return false
    }
    
    func cgImageToData(_ cgImage: CGImage) -> Data? {
        let width = cgImage.width
        let height = cgImage.height
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4 // Assuming 4 bytes per pixel
        let totalBytes = bytesPerRow * height
        
        var pixelData = Data(count: totalBytes)
        pixelData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr in
            guard let context = CGContext(data: ptr.baseAddress,
                                          width: width,
                                          height: height,
                                          bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                          bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                          space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                          bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else {
                print("Error: Unable to create bitmap context")
                return
            }
            context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))
        }
        
        return pixelData
    }
    
    // Convert CGImage to JPEG to reduce memory footprint
    //Not Implemented
    private func cgImageToJPEGData(_ cgImage: CGImage) -> Data? {
        let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) // Compress to reduce memory usage
    }
    
    private func getCameraInfo() -> String{
        let height = self.height
        let width = self.width
        let distortionModel = "plumb_bob"
        var D :[Double] = D
        var K :[Double] = K
        var R :[Double] = R
        var P :[Double] = P
        let binning_X = 1
        let binning_Y = 1

        
        //Fill DKRP values
        
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let sec = Int(timestamp)
        let nsec = Int((timestamp - Double(sec)) * 1_000_000_000)
        
        let json: [String: Any] = [
            "op": "publish",
            "topic": "/camera/camera_info",
            "msg": [
                "header": [
                    "frame_id": "camera",
                    "stamp": [
                        "sec": sec,
                        "nsec": nsec
                    ]
                ],
                "height": height,
                "width": width,
                "distortion_model": distortionModel,
                "D": D,
                "K": K,
                "R": R,
                "P": P,
                "binning_x": binning_X,
                "binning_y": binning_Y,
                "roi": [
                    "x_offset": 0,
                    "y_offset": 0,
                    "height": height,
                    "width": width,
                    "do_rectify": false
                ]
            ]
        ]
        
        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "{}"
        } else {
            return "{}"
        }
    }
    
    private func convertToJSON(imageData: Data, height: Int, width: Int, encoding: String, step: Int) -> String {
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let sec = Int(timestamp)
        let nsec = Int((timestamp - Double(sec)) * 1_000_000_000)
        let imageArray = [UInt8](imageData)
        
        let json: [String: Any] = [
            "op": "publish",
            "topic": "/camera",
            "msg": [
                "header": [
                    "frame_id": "camera",
                    "stamp": [
                        "sec": sec,
                        "nsec": nsec
                    ]
                ],
                "height": height,
                "width": width,
                "encoding": encoding,
                "is_bigendian": 0,
                "step": step,
                "data": imageArray
            ]
        ]
        
        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            return String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "{}"
        } else {
            return "{}"
        }
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - ARSession Delegate Method for Point Cloud
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        guard currentTime - lastSendTime >= minInterval else { return }
        lastSendTime = currentTime

        var combinedPointCloud: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)] = []

        // Extract point cloud from the depth data
        if let sceneDepth = frame.sceneDepth {
            if let depthPointCloud = extractPointCloudFromDepth(frame: frame, depthData: sceneDepth) {
                combinedPointCloud += depthPointCloud
            }
            
            // Present an error message to the user
            print("ARSession failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                if let arError = error as? ARError {
                    switch arError.errorCode {
                    case 102:
                        config.worldAlignment = .gravity
                        restartSessionWithoutDelete()
                    default:
                        restartSessionWithoutDelete()
                    }
                }
        }

        // Add points from the mesh anchors
        combinedPointCloud += convertMeshToPointCloud(anchors: frame.anchors)

        // Send point cloud to ROS
        if !combinedPointCloud.isEmpty {
            sendPointCloudToROS(pointCloud: combinedPointCloud)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func restartSessionWithoutDelete() {
        // Restart session with a different worldAlignment - prevents bug from crashing app
        self.session.pause()
        self.session.run(config, options: [
            .resetTracking,
            .removeExistingAnchors])
    }

    
    func sendPointCloudToROS(pointCloud: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)]) {
        guard !pointCloud.isEmpty else { return }
        
        // Get the current timestamp
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        let sec = Int(timestamp)
        let nsec = Int((timestamp - Double(sec)) * 1_000_000_000)
        
        // Create the ROS message
        let json: [String: Any] = [
            "op": "publish",
            "topic": "/point_cloud",
            "msg": [
                "header": [
                    "frame_id": "camara",
                    "stamp": [
                        "sec": sec,
                        "nsec": nsec
                    ]
                ],
                "height": 1, // Unstructured point cloud
                "width": pointCloud.count,
                "fields": [
                    ["name": "x", "offset": 0, "datatype": 7, "count": 1], // datatype 7 = FLOAT32
                    ["name": "y", "offset": 4, "datatype": 7, "count": 1],
                    ["name": "z", "offset": 8, "datatype": 7, "count": 1]
                ],
                "is_bigendian": false,
                "point_step": 12, // 4 bytes each for x, y, z
                "row_step": 12 * pointCloud.count,
                "data": encodePointCloudData(pointCloud),
                "is_dense": true
            ]
        ]
        
        // Convert the JSON to a string
        if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted) {
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "{}"
            webSocketManager.send(message: jsonString)
        }
    }
    
    private func encodePointCloudData(_ pointCloud: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)]) -> [UInt8] {
        var data = [UInt8]()
        for point in pointCloud {
            var x = point.x
            var y = point.y
            var z = point.z
            withUnsafeBytes(of: &x) { data.append(contentsOf: $0) }
            withUnsafeBytes(of: &y) { data.append(contentsOf: $0) }
            withUnsafeBytes(of: &z) { data.append(contentsOf: $0) }
        }
        return data
    }
    
    //MARK: - Extract Point Cloud Data from Depth Map
    private func extractPointCloudFromDepth(frame: ARFrame, depthData: ARDepthData) -> [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)]? {
        guard let intrinsics = getCameraIntrinsics(from: frame) else { return [] }
        
        let (fx, fy, cx, cy) = (intrinsics.fx, intrinsics.fy, intrinsics.cx, intrinsics.cy)
        let depthMap = depthData.depthMap
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthMap)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthMap)
        
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(depthMap, .readOnly)
        defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(depthMap, .readOnly) }
        
        guard let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthMap) else { return [] }
        let rowBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(depthMap)
        
        var pointCloud: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)] = []
        
        for y in stride(from: 0, to: height, by: 2) { // Process every 2nd row for speed
            for x in stride(from: 0, to: width, by: 2) { // Process every 2nd column
                let depth = baseAddress
                    .advanced(by: y * rowBytes + x * MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
                    .assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
                    .pointee
                if depth > 0 {
                    let xWorld = (Float(x) - cx) * depth / fx
                    let yWorld = (Float(y) - cy) * depth / fy
                    let zWorld = depth
                    pointCloud.append((x: xWorld, y: yWorld, z: zWorld))
                }
                // Skip invalid depth values
                if depth == 0 {
                    continue
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        // Unlock the base address after reading the pixel data
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(depthMap, .readOnly)
        
        return pointCloud
    }
    
    // MARK: - Retrieve Camera Intrinsics
    private func getCameraIntrinsics(from frame: ARFrame) -> (fx: Float, fy: Float, cx: Float, cy: Float)? {
        // Camera intrinsics are stored in the ARFrame's camera properties
        let intrinsics = frame.camera.intrinsics
        
        let fx = intrinsics[0, 0]
        let fy = intrinsics[1, 1]
        let cx = intrinsics[0, 2]
        let cy = intrinsics[1, 2]
        
        return (fx, fy, cx, cy)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Convert Mesh to Point Cloud Data
    private func convertMeshToPointCloud(anchors: [ARAnchor]) -> [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)] {
        var pointCloud: [(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)] = []
        
        for anchor in anchors {
            guard let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor else { continue }
            let geometry = meshAnchor.geometry
            
            let vertexBuffer = geometry.vertices
            let vertexData = vertexBuffer.buffer.contents() // Get the raw buffer pointer
            
            // Iterate over the vertices
            for i in 0..<vertexBuffer.count {
                let vertexPointer = vertexData.advanced(by: i * vertexBuffer.stride)
                let vertex = vertexPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: simd_float3.self).pointee
                
                // Transform vertex into world space using the anchor's transform
                let worldVertex = simd_make_float4(vertex, 1.0)
                let transformedVertex = meshAnchor.transform * worldVertex
                
                pointCloud.append((x: transformedVertex.x, y: transformedVertex.y, z: transformedVertex.z))
            }
        }
        
        return pointCloud
    }
    
    
    
}


The code builds successfuly but gives me the error: ARSession: Did fail with error: Code 102: "Required Sensor Failed".
I have tried using the function restartSessionWithoutDelete() and modifying the function session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame, didFailWithError error: Error) to solve the problem. Additionally, I reset both the device and the Mac, but it still did not work.
If someone could explain what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.
